# Retrieve MySQL data with webservice to create FTP Folder and user/pass?

Tags: mysql, vb.net, web-services, ftp, wsdl

I need to create something that will retrieve new Users from a VTiger CRM and create a FTP folder and user/pass on another server.

SERV-A: VTiger CRM, powered by MYSQL. With WSDL directory.

SERV-B: FTP server

The reason why I thought doing a WebService is that I must constantly check for new users.

The language used isn't an issue.

**The question is:** How to automatically retrieve changes of a MySQL DB from a webservice // Better solution ??

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My company does something similar for our app.  We have several different scripts written in PHP running on a set schedule (cron) that queries something (we talk to local DB's, various different web services and application API's, even scrub an email address) and use that information to "do things" such as DB updates and mail jobs.  So it'd just be a matter of writing a script activated by cron that makes a WSDL call, if it returns values then build the FTP user.  Here's a fairly in-depth post on how to do that:

http://forums.devshed.com/ftp-help-113/need-create-new-ftp-account-via-php-109381.html

Comment: Great ! Thanks for the tip. I'll check this on